# Proper syntax for get-item command, for dynamodb of the aws

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am writing get-item command for dynamodb of the aws.
Here is my command:

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name foo --key '{\" bar \":{\"S\":\"aaaa\"},\"timestamp\":{\"N\":\"1603610188890\"}}'
```

As you can see, the table foo has composite primary key:
partition key "bar" and sort key "timestamp".
What is the proper syntax to use comparison for the sort key "timestamp"?
How I can to change my command to get the items whose timestamp is between 1603010188890 and 1603610188890?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [get-item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/get-item.html) operation can only retrieve a single item, with a specific key. To retrieve items - possibly more than one - in a certain sort-key range you need to use a different request - [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/query.html).

The "query" request has a `key-conditions` or `key-condition-expression` (these are the older and newer, respectively, syntax, for the same thing). With that parameter you can say that you want items where the partition key is equal something, and the sort key is between two values.